# My animated Items disappear when on mobile

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

I had this problem before, I thought it was because the images were lazy loaded but now its doing it with text, I'm using tailwind with NextJS this is my code

coinBanner.tsx

```
<div className="w-max flex gap-8 relative bg-gray-900 text-white h-12 items-center ">
      <div className="flex gap-8  animate-sliding ">
        <p>Trending</p>
        {store.coins.map((item: coinType) => {
          return (
            <p className="overflow-visible" key={item.symbol}>
              {item.symbol}
              <span className="pl-1">${item.priceUsd}</span>
            </p>
          );
        })}
      </div>
      <div className="flex gap-8  animate-sliding ">
        <p>Trending</p>
        {store.coins.map((item: coinType) => {
          return (
            <p className="overflow-visible" key={item.symbol}>
              {item.symbol}
              <span className="pl-1">${item.priceUsd}</span>
            </p>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
```

Tailwind.config.ts

```
const config: Config = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        "gradient-radial": "radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
        "gradient-conic":
          "conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
      },
      keyframes: {
        slide: {
          "0%": { transform: "translateX(-100%)" },
          "100%": { transform: "translateX(0%)" },
        },
      },
      animation: {
        sliding: "slide 15s linear infinite",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

I want the images to infinitely slide to the left